# JqueryUI portlets not loading (sometimes). .

Tags: jquery-ui, loading, portlet

so we are using jQueryUI's portlets on our dashboard and about 10% of the time everything loads on the page except for the portlets. After clicking refresh they then load correctly. Is this a plugin issue or framework issue that anyone know about? I would appreciate a fix.

Comment: Travis, when asking question you should provide more details about the problem.

- Your scenario. E.g. version of jQueryUI, what widgets are you displaying? Does this/does not happen in all browsers?
- When you run into this, what errors are you seeing exactly?

This will help other people to understand the problem and help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to review the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour It is also best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example